# c# tapi application for central

Tags: c#, tapi

I am attempting to use c# TAPI application in my central, my purpose is that i want to call from the tapi application after specifying the extension of device in my central, this mean that i want to specify the extension that want dialing a call using my tapi application, is this possible?

This is the link of c# tapi app I use: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10994/TAPI-Application-development-using-C-NET

Note that the type of my central is siemens Hipath 3550

Comment: Tread with caution: TAPI programming with .NET is fraught with difficulties due to the way .NET wraps the COM layer automatically.  You may find that it works fine for a lot of the time, but then suddenly inexplicably not work.

Comment: so you said that i can't use TAPI application to make calls from my central devices using the app? if yes did you know another tool or c# library that can enable this service ?

Comment: You _can_ use .NET, but it may not be completely reliable.  It's partly related to the underlying TAPI driver too, you might get lucky and be completely fine.

Comment: can I use another that .NET? I mean is their a similar app for tapi to use in java for example and it must dial call specifying the extension of device in my central?

Comment: There's lots of various libraries around for dealing with TAPI.  I don't know about any for java specifically, and library recommendations are off topic for Stack Overflow really.  Have you tried to use the code in that Code Project link?  Did you get anywhere?  Perhaps edit your question to include what you've tried and what did/didn't work?

Comment: this code working fine when i want to dial from my laptop, the problem is that i want to specify the extension of the device to dial from, my question is how can i do that using this library, maybe it is not possible

Comment: It depends whether the tapi driver supports first party only or allows third party too.  If it's first party only, then the tapi lines that are set up on your computer are the only ones you can control.  If it _does_ support third party, you probably need different code to call those functions anyway.  Personally, I've only ever dealt with first party drivers/code.

Comment: what is 'those functions' and how i can get them? also how i can now if it support third party or not?

Comment: It ought to say what modes it supports in its documentation.  I don't know what code changes you'd have to make to support third party calls; as mentioned, I've never done so.

Comment: since you have already working on .net tapi app, would you recommend to use .NET tAPI application or to search for another telephony applications?

Comment: If you're doing a lot of work with TAPI with multiple different providers (doesn't sound like it), I'd look for a library that does all the hard work for you - there are lots out there.  It makes interfacing with .NET far easier.  Personally, I've written a C++/CLI wrapper to handle the COM layer transition into .NET.